# Replace the arrow with a Line in bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c5nfg69g/)**

I got this Bootstrap popover working but I have to modify the arrow into a horizontal line. This applies for both left and right side of the popover.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm looking to modify into:
[image]

I believe there's going to be a lot of CSS changes but don't know where to start from.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="Some content">Hover Left</a> | 
<a href="#" title="Header" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-content="Some content">Hover Right</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20% auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created the the left popover with line border. Hope You can create the right popover. Add bellow css code into your .css file

```
.container {
text-align: center;
margin: 20% auto;
width: 100%;
}
.popover.left{
 margin-left: -30px
}

.popover .arrow{
  border-width: 1px;
}
.popover.left .arrow:after {
right: -20px;
bottom: -12px;
}
.popover .arrow:after {
border-width: 0px;
content: "";
width: 30px;
height: 1px;
background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Super Awesome! Thank you. I'll recreate the others :)

Comment: You are Welcome :)